# Using posterior as prior: references

Tags: bayesian

Could someone suggest some references of papers that use posteriors of previous experiments/research as priors in their own analysis? Or, in particular, papers that replicate a given study and use the posterior of the original study as the prior for the replicated one?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any references?

Comment: Not really. Suggestions?